# Why are black dots in my nav? (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css, nav

I'll be quick. I know the code is not debugged, I have only an hour in it, and I already have a bug and I don't know how to fix it, I made a nav the way it is shown in the code. I use `text-decoration:none;` to hide the underlining but some black points are shown, I do not know if it is text decoration or what.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"     href="style.css">
<title>stdd</title>
</head>

<body>

<h2>FRASE PAGINA WEB</h2>
<h1>TITULO PAGINA WEB</h1>

<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Albumes</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Centerfolder</a><li>
</ul>
</nav>

<div id="leftbox">
<article><img src="1.jpg"><p><b>Explora y sobrevive en la oscuridad de un mundo de pesadilla.</b></p></article>
<article><img src="2.jpg"><p><b>Salva la galaxia con tu nave y con la ayuda los gatitos espaciales!</b></p></article>
<article><img src="3.jpg"><p><b>Tus acciones cuenta soladado! La guerra nunca habia sido tan real.</b></p></article>
</div>

<aside>
<p>Aqui pueden ir anuncios, tags, comentarios de redes sociales, un buscador, la radio, cualquier gadget, algun javascript, una imagen, un gif, puntuacion, suscribirse por correo, hora, calendario, miniblog...</p>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

```
<div id="rightbox">
<article><img src="4.jpg"><p><b>Todos tenemos nuestro lado psicopata... Acaba con todos de mil maneras!</b>.</p></article>
<article><img src="5.jpg"><p><b>Sin manos, sin piernas, grandes cualidades.</b></p><br></article>
<article><img src="6.jpg"><p><b>Desde naves hasta estaciones espaciales, el espacio en manos de tu ingenio!</b></p></article>
```

```
<footer>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
*{padding:0; margin:0; text-decoration:none;}

body{background:#cb8015;}

h1{color:yellow; text-align:center; font-size:50px;}

h2{color:yellow; text-align:center; margin-top:6px;     font-size:40px;}

article img{width:100%; border-top:solid white 3px;     border-bottom:solid white 3px;}

#leftbox{width:39%; float:left;}
#leftbox p{text-align:right; margin-right:10%; margin-    left:10%; margin-bottom:10px; font-size:23px;}

aside{background:black; width:22%; float:left;}
aside p{color:white; padding:10px; font-size:30px;}

#rightbox{width:39%; float:left;}
#rightbox p{text-align:left; margin-right:10%;     margin-left:10%; margin-bottom:10px; font-size:23px;}


nav{overflow:hidden; border-top:solid orange 3px;}
nav ul li{float:left;}
nav ul li a{display:block; font-size:28px; color:white; padding:1px 5px;}
nav ul li a:hover{background:black;}
```

Some things like the `<br>` amateur fix or the bad colors are only temporary to see how it goes.

Comment: Thank everybody for the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bydefault `ul` tag take bullets in list items. You can remove this by using `nav ul {list-style: none;}`. Check updated snippet below..

```css
*{padding:0; margin:0; text-decoration:none;}

body{background:#cb8015;}

h1{color:yellow; text-align:center; font-size:50px;}

h2{color:yellow; text-align:center; margin-top:6px;     font-size:40px;}

article img{width:100%; border-top:solid white 3px;     border-bottom:solid white 3px;}

#leftbox{width:39%; float:left;}
#leftbox p{text-align:right; margin-right:10%; margin-    left:10%; margin-bottom:10px; font-size:23px;}

aside{background:black; width:22%; float:left;}
aside p{color:white; padding:10px; font-size:30px;}

#rightbox{width:39%; float:left;}
#rightbox p{text-align:left; margin-right:10%;     margin-left:10%; margin-bottom:10px; font-size:23px;}


nav{overflow:hidden; border-top:solid orange 3px;}
nav ul {list-style: none;}
nav ul li{float:left;}
nav ul li a{display:block; font-size:28px; color:white; padding:1px 5px;}
nav ul li a:hover{background:black;}
```

```html
<h2>FRASE PAGINA WEB</h2>
<h1>TITULO PAGINA WEB</h1>

<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Albumes</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Centerfolder</a><li>
</ul>
</nav>

<div id="leftbox">
<article><img src="1.jpg"><p><b>Explora y sobrevive en la oscuridad de un mundo de pesadilla.</b></p></article>
<article><img src="2.jpg"><p><b>Salva la galaxia con tu nave y con la ayuda los gatitos espaciales!</b></p></article>
<article><img src="3.jpg"><p><b>Tus acciones cuenta soladado! La guerra nunca habia sido tan real.</b></p></article>
</div>

<aside>
<p>Aqui pueden ir anuncios, tags, comentarios de redes sociales, un buscador, la radio, cualquier gadget, algun javascript, una imagen, un gif, puntuacion, suscribirse por correo, hora, calendario, miniblog...</p>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div id="rightbox">
<article><img src="4.jpg"><p><b>Todos tenemos nuestro lado psicopata... Acaba con todos de mil maneras!</b>.</p></article>
<article><img src="5.jpg"><p><b>Sin manos, sin piernas, grandes cualidades.</b></p><br></article>
<article><img src="6.jpg"><p><b>Desde naves hasta estaciones espaciales, el espacio en manos de tu ingenio!</b></p></article>

<footer>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check That, `nav ul li{float:left; list-style-type: none;}`

```css
*{padding:0; margin:0; text-decoration:none;}

body{background:#cb8015;}

h1{color:yellow; text-align:center; font-size:50px;}

h2{color:yellow; text-align:center; margin-top:6px;     font-size:40px;}

article img{width:100%; border-top:solid white 3px;     border-bottom:solid white 3px;}

#leftbox{width:39%; float:left;}
#leftbox p{text-align:right; margin-right:10%; margin-    left:10%; margin-bottom:10px; font-size:23px;}

aside{background:black; width:22%; float:left;}
aside p{color:white; padding:10px; font-size:30px;}

#rightbox{width:39%; float:left;}
#rightbox p{text-align:left; margin-right:10%;     margin-left:10%; margin-bottom:10px; font-size:23px;}


nav{overflow:hidden; border-top:solid orange 3px;}
nav ul li{float:left; list-style-type: none;}
nav ul li a{display:block; font-size:28px; color:white; padding:1px 5px;}
nav ul li a:hover{background:black;}
```

```html
<h2>FRASE PAGINA WEB</h2>
<h1>TITULO PAGINA WEB</h1>

<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Albumes</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Centerfolder</a><li>
</ul>
</nav>

<div id="leftbox">
<article><img src="1.jpg"><p><b>Explora y sobrevive en la oscuridad de un mundo de pesadilla.</b></p></article>
<article><img src="2.jpg"><p><b>Salva la galaxia con tu nave y con la ayuda los gatitos espaciales!</b></p></article>
<article><img src="3.jpg"><p><b>Tus acciones cuenta soladado! La guerra nunca habia sido tan real.</b></p></article>
</div>

<aside>
<p>Aqui pueden ir anuncios, tags, comentarios de redes sociales, un buscador, la radio, cualquier gadget, algun javascript, una imagen, un gif, puntuacion, suscribirse por correo, hora, calendario, miniblog...</p>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div id="rightbox">
<article><img src="4.jpg"><p><b>Todos tenemos nuestro lado psicopata... Acaba con todos de mil maneras!</b>.</p></article>
<article><img src="5.jpg"><p><b>Sin manos, sin piernas, grandes cualidades.</b></p><br></article>
<article><img src="6.jpg"><p><b>Desde naves hasta estaciones espaciales, el espacio en manos de tu ingenio!</b></p></article>

<footer>
</footer>
```

Comment: Lol Soo fast. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just Add 'list-style:none' css Property :

```css
*{padding:0; margin:0; text-decoration:none;}

body{background:#cb8015;}

h1{color:yellow; text-align:center; font-size:50px;}

h2{color:yellow; text-align:center; margin-top:6px;     font-size:40px;}

article img{width:100%; border-top:solid white 3px;     border-bottom:solid white 3px;}

#leftbox{width:39%; float:left;}
#leftbox p{text-align:right; margin-right:10%; margin-    left:10%; margin-bottom:10px; font-size:23px;}

aside{background:black; width:22%; float:left;}
aside p{color:white; padding:10px; font-size:30px;}
ul li{
  list-style:none;
}
#rightbox{width:39%; float:left;}
#rightbox p{text-align:left; margin-right:10%;     margin-left:10%; margin-bottom:10px; font-size:23px;}


nav{overflow:hidden; border-top:solid orange 3px;}
nav ul li{float:left;}
nav ul li a{display:block; font-size:28px; color:white; padding:1px 5px;}
nav ul li a:hover{background:black;}
```

```html
<body>

<h2>FRASE PAGINA WEB</h2>
<h1>TITULO PAGINA WEB</h1>

<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Albumes</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Centerfolder</a><li>
</ul>
</nav>

<div id="leftbox">
<article><img src="1.jpg"><p><b>Explora y sobrevive en la oscuridad de un mundo de pesadilla.</b></p></article>
<article><img src="2.jpg"><p><b>Salva la galaxia con tu nave y con la ayuda los gatitos espaciales!</b></p></article>
<article><img src="3.jpg"><p><b>Tus acciones cuenta soladado! La guerra nunca habia sido tan real.</b></p></article>
</div>

<aside>
<p>Aqui pueden ir anuncios, tags, comentarios de redes sociales, un buscador, la radio, cualquier gadget, algun javascript, una imagen, un gif, puntuacion, suscribirse por correo, hora, calendario, miniblog...</p>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div id="rightbox">
<article><img src="4.jpg"><p><b>Todos tenemos nuestro lado psicopata... Acaba con todos de mil maneras!</b>.</p></article>
<article><img src="5.jpg"><p><b>Sin manos, sin piernas, grandes cualidades.</b></p><br></article>
<article><img src="6.jpg"><p><b>Desde naves hasta estaciones espaciales, el espacio en manos de tu ingenio!</b></p></article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this css:

```
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```